# Несколько har файлов и java -jar

Tags: java, jar

Здравствуйте, такой вопрос:
Есть основной .jar файл (назовем его main.jar), для работы с ним требуется использовать еще 2 .jar файла (через classpath), назовем их add1.jar и add2.jar.
Вроде все просто: java -cp add1.jar:add2.jar:main.jar
Проблема в следующем: в связи с некоторыми ограничениями ПО, запускающего основной .jar файл НЕ можем использовать -cp, а точнее для ПО обязательно должен быть указан .jar файл, который нужно запускать. Можно ли как-то подключить эти 2 дополнительных .jar файла, без использования -cp в строке запуска?

Comment: в `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` `main.jar` написать `Class-Path: add1.jar add2.jar` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Comment: пробовал (там уже есть пачка .jar`ников),но в результате все равно не видит то, что в add1/add2.jar

Comment: И путь манифесте прописан? `Class-path: /path/to/addr1.jar`?

Comment: Извините, мой косяк. Class-path прописал,а `jarники не добавил :)